Is there a quantitative method for measuring vibration damping and frame comfort?
Discussions about frame strength or tire rolling resistance can be quantitative: occasionally someone will provide objective evaluations.
But one topic that resists quantifying is comfort. Various pundits tell us about (and we ourselves may feel, possibly by placebo) carbon frames' superiority. Others will suggest that, done well, a titanium frame is nearly as comfortable as its carbon sibling.
Does there exist a method for quantifying vibration damping in bicycle frames? Basically I'm looking for experiments and numbers that indicate the relative comfort of one kind of frame material compared to another, rather than for the subjective impressions of a cycling journalist.
It could be, for instance, that the natural frequency of a steel alloy, aluminum alloy, titanium alloy, or composite frame is within a given range. It could be that at various riding speeds, the frequency of tarmac irregularities also arise in some range. One conclusion could potentially be that a composite frame is incapable of transmitting vibrations to the rider — leading to a more comfortable endurance ride — because the two ranges have little or no overlap, whereas there is an overlap for the other material.
Is there a quantitative method for measuring frame comfort?
Related

carbon vs aluminium frame vibration absorption? bumpiness?
Advice needed re Carbon Fiber vs Shocks
How to reduce vibrations to handlebars on aluminium road bike
Reconciling the two aspects: carbon is stiffer for power, but offers a softer ride
https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/61663/36266

Prequels and Sequels (edit)

As David D asks, a preliminary question is whether vibration damping is a factor, or the only factor, resulting in frame comfort. Feel free to refute (perhaps in an answer) if you can argue that these two are not synonymous.
Context of the question: at various times one reads a variation of "you're better off buying a better aluminum frame than a middling carbon frame." On what basis are these statements made? Likewise some remain fans of steel alloys or titanium alloys. Why, objectively?
This question is a sequel to an earlier question: how can a frame be simultaneously very rigid for power transfer, yet be comfortable because it absorbs road vibration (and for heaven's sake: don't talk about different carbon fiber layering unless you can specify the structure that simultaneously yields these two benefits).


Not posting as an answer, as it’s only a link, but cyclingabout.com has a methodology that they use in their reviews (limited to gravel and touring bikes).

@Rеnаud Nice to see someone trying to figure it out. His choice of measuring at 500Hz seems suboptimal given that litterature in general seems to have most concern for low frequency vibrations around 0-100hz with regard to health issues. Discomfort might not be fully correlated with harm though. And his frequency choice might be reasonable on a bike or just a result of his equipment's limitations with no regard to reasonableness. 10/10 for effort though. No reason why it can't be done, how it is best done, and if anyone have done it properly is another question.

@Renaud Who would have thought that the answer would be as simple as "mount a seismometer on each bike, ride along the same road — and compare the averages of each graph"? There are even apps for that. Search for "seismometer". Please add as an answer. It's not clear we're going to have a better answer.

@Rеnаud Great link. I read the article and I think I've looked at all the linked articles and I have two thoughts on Krzysztof Wierzbicki's work. First, I can't find any actual comparison data. A graph that shows the measurements for different bikes. There is one for tire inflation but nothing on frames or bikes. Second, his work does not attempt to answer the question posed here about frame stiffness. He equates less vibration with more comfort and he measures on the handlebar and under the seat. His goal is not to isolate and measure frame vibration.

@DavidD there’s indeed no general comparison data, the reviews have data against a reference bike, that has changed over time. On the tires he says that they are inflated at a high pressure, wit the aim to keep the same casing tension if there are different widths. The goal is indeed not isolate only the frame, but rather frame + seatpost + stem. One can argue that now that all these components become proprietary and integrated, isolating the frame only may not be relevant in all cases.

I would argue that damping is not the only factor in confort, I think (longer) wheelbase plays towards confort too. A longer wheelbase puts the rider in the center of a longer lever arm, thus, up/down movement of one wheel is reduced a little more when transmitted to the saddle. Even if it´s just a little, it may be enough to subjectively qualify a frame as more comfortable than another of similar build.

Basically, given the comments, it seems to me that because the phenomenon of comfort is a complex one, at least part of the assessment needs to be subjective. You can create and validate scales to measure subjective phenomena. If you've ever taken a depression screening questionnaire in primary care, you've just filled out something that quantifies a subjective phenomena, albeit with imprecision and other caveats. With some complex phenomena, the subjectivity isn't bad, it's just part of the game.

@WeiwenNg Perhaps. Perhaps some people enjoy getting a massage while riding their bicycles, not unlike Wagyu herds get pampered. It's even possible that we riders end up with our body fat spread out inside muscle tissue, and this could somehow be a good thing. Still, it's pretty clear to me that comfort is not subjective at all. I may not notice very much, nor care, on a 10-km bike ride. On a 40-km ride I do notice a little, but on a 100-km ride (my farthest so far) it's crystal clear during the second half whether the bike is comfortable.

@WeiwenNg One reason to seek a "vibration-damping coefficient" or some such metric is to be able to assess a bike I intend to ride far, without actually riding it far. A bike shop that already knows me might let me take a bike out for an hour (normally that's rather generous), but that will still not take me very far.

Methods for quantifying vibration in bicycle frames have been developed.
The article "Measurement of dynamic vibration in cycling using portable terminal measurement system" describes the creation of a system for measuring bicycle vibration.

This study presents simple and robust systems for bicycle vibration measurement which is easily transferable and portable. Two sets of bicycle vibration information acquisition schemes founded on the portable terminal are proposed. Scheme (1) is based on the independent devices of the IPB. Scheme (2) is an integrated test system based on the Arduino Mega 2560 microcontroller containing three modules.

The study takes data from the handlebar, the seat post and the downtube.
The article "Development of a test rig and a testing procedure for bicycle frame stiffness measurements" seeks to focus on just the frame.
Project goal from the abstract

The stiffness measuring method for bicycle frames is not standardized, leading to a wide variety of test setups; they differ in many aspects such as applied load, support constraints and frame deflection measurement. The aim of this paper is to draw attention to this problem and to quantify the perturbing, unwanted side effects that influence the stiffness measurement of the bicycle frame. This is illustrated by developing a multi-purpose rating test method for bicycle frame stiffness.


It's one thing to attach sensors to different parts of a bike and call it a method of measuring vibration. It's another thing to systematically run tests, gather and evaluate data and turn the information into some kind of meaningful result. A few of the questions that might arise would be;

What is the relationship between vibration and comfort?
Are all vibrations bad?
What is the relationship between vibration and efficiency?

I would suspect that tire size and tire inflation has a larger effect on vibration than the frame. Some day we may have the data to prove me wrong.
